# Fetching data from two tables and joining them together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called participant_tb, the columns of the table are like this

> participant_id : 1, username: 'atom', fullname: 'abc' participant_id:
> 2, username : 'ion', fullname: 'def' participant_id: 3, username:
> 'molecule', fullname: 'ghi' participant_id: 4, username: 'compound',
> fullname: 'jkl'

I have another table that looks like this, the table is called follower_tb

> follow_id: 1, follower_id: 1, followed_id: 2, follow_id: 2,
> follower_id: 2, followed_id: 1, follow_id: 3, follower_id: 3,
> followed_id: 1, follow_id: 4, follower_id: 1, followed_id: 4.

Once someone clicks on the follow button, the id of the follower will be stored in the follower_id and the id of the person that is followed will be stored in the followed_id columns. What I want to do is this: let's say "atom' with the participant_id of 1 loggedin, I want to fetch the list of those he is following and those following him.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT p.participant_id, p.username, p.fullname, f.follower_username, f.followed_username, f.follower_id
FROM my_participants p
JOIN my_followers f ON ( p.participant_id = f.followed_id ) 
WHERE followed_id =  1 || follower_id =  1
```

The problem I have with this is that, it only fetched those that are following atom.

I also tried this

```
SELECT p.participant_id, p.username, p.fullname, f.follower_username, f.followed_username, f.follower_id
FROM my_participants p
JOIN my_followers f ON ( p.participant_id = f.follower_id ) 
WHERE followed_id =  1 || follower_id =  1
```

The problem I have with this is that, it includes atom in its result.
Producing something like this

> participant_id: 1, username: 'atom', follower_id: 1, followed_id: 2,
>
> participant_id: 2, username: 'ion', follower_id: 1, followed_id: 2,
>
> participant_id: 1, username: 'atom', follower_id: 2, followed_id: 1,
> participant_id: 2, username: 'ion', follower_id: 2, followed_id: 1,
> participant_id: 3, username: 'molecule', follower_id: 3, followed_id:
> 1,
> participant_id: 1, username: 'atom', follower_id: 3, followed_id:
> 1,
> participant_id: 4, username: 'compound', follower_id: 1,
> followed_id: 4
> participant_id: 1, username: 'atoom', follower_id: 1,
> followed_id: 4

I want something like this:

> participant_id: 2, username: 'ion', follower_id: 1, followed_id: 2,
> participant_id: 2, username: 'ion', follower_id: 2, followed_id: 1,
> participant_id: 3, username: 'molecule', follower_id: 3, followed_id:
> 1, participant_id: 4, username: 'compound', follower_id: 1,
> followed_id: 4

or something like this (this first line shows atom is following this person and the person is following back):

> participant_id: 2, username: 'ion', follower_id: 2, followed_id: 2,
> participant_id: 3, username: 'molecule', follower_id: 3, followed_id:
> 1,
> participant_id: 4, username: 'compound', follower_id: 1,
> followed_id: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT p.participant_id, p.username, p.fullname, f.follower_username, f.followed_username, f.follower_id
FROM my_participants p
JOIN my_followers f ON ( p.participant_id = f.follower_id || p.participant_id = f.followed_id ) 
WHERE p.participant_id !=1 and ( f.followed_id =  1 || f.follower_id =  1)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for a [SQL Subquery](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery), which lets you use the result(s) of one query as the input for another. As it turns out, the queries to fetch followers and followees are very similar.

```
#select those FOLLOWING the logged-in account

SELECT p.participant_id, p.username, f.follower_id, f.followed_id FROM participant_tb AS p
JOIN follower_tb AS f ON (p.participant_id = f.follower_id)
WHERE p.participant_id IN (
    #make a sub-query to fetch the follower_id's of the entries that follow participant_id 1

    SELECT f.follower_id
    FROM participant_tb AS p
    JOIN follower_tb AS f ON (p.participant_id = f.followed_id)
    WHERE participant_id = 1 #your value here
);
```

The subquery picks out each `follower_id` that is following `participant_id` 1, and then uses that list of ids to pick the usernames out of `participant_tb`.

```
#select those BEING FOLLOWED BY the logged-in account

SELECT p.participant_id, p.username, f.follower_id, f.followed_id FROM participant_tb AS p
JOIN follower_tb AS f ON (p.participant_id = f.followed_id)
WHERE p.participant_id IN (
    #make a sub-query to fetch the follower_id's of the entries that are being followed by participant_id 1

    SELECT f.followed_id
    FROM participant_tb AS p
    JOIN follower_tb AS f ON (p.participant_id = f.follower_id)
    WHERE participant_id = 1 #your value here
);
```

This subquery is almost identical, but it selects the `followed_id` of all elements that are being followed by `participant_id` 1.

The returned values of query 1:

```
particiapnt_id  username    follower_id followed_id
2               ion         2           1
3               molecule    3           1
```

The returned values of query 2:

```
particiapnt_id  username    follower_id followed_id
2               ion         1           2
4               compound    1           4
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, the first query fetched 0 rows and also the subquery. Can you take another look into it to see what is wrong?

Comment: It's worth noting that I used slightly different table names in my queries than you did in your examples - did you check to make sure all the table names matched your definitions?

Comment: yes,   I did. If the names were different, it would throw back an error

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue would be, in that case. The only other things that come to mind are the ID you tested not having any followers, the tables have mismatched IDs, one or more tables don't have data in them (I've made this mistake a lot...), or some sort of issue with the formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken another look into it, I tested it with an id that doesn't have a follower but when I tested it with one that has followers, it brought out unexpected results. The result I got fetched data that aren't related to participant id: 1. Something like this: particpant_id: 3, username: molecule, follower_id: 3, followed_id: 2. As shown here, no information is related to participant_id of 1, he is not the follower and he is not the person that is being followed

Comment: I think it brought out the followers of those following 'atom'(participant_id of 1) and those they are following

Comment: That sounds like you may accidentally be using `follow_id` instead of `follower_id` or`followed_id` somewhere in the query. Can you provide more info about the query you're using, how you're calling it, and/or the table formats? Are you trying to merge the two SELECT statements into one single query? The more information we have, the better we can help.

Comment: Finally, I've gotten it, this is what I wrote: SELECT p.participant_id, p.username, p.fullname, f.follower_username, f.followed_username, f.follower_id
FROM my_participants p
JOIN my_followers f ON ( p.participant_id = f.follower_id || p.participant_id = f.followed_id ) 
WHERE p.participant_id !=1 and ( followed_id =  1 || follower_id =  1)    I wouldn't have gotten it without your help and suggestions, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

SELECT p.participant_id, p.username, p.fullname, f.follower_username, f.followed_username, f.follower_id
FROM my_participants p
JOIN my_followers f ON ( ( p.participant_id = f.follower_id ) or ( p.participant_id = f.followed_id ))

Comment: Thank you, I tried this (I only added where follower_id = 1 or followed_id = 1) but I encountered one of the problems I stated while asking the question, which is: it also fetched the details of  'atom' which is not what I want.